# Get "Floating point exception" while running php-fpm after adding "extension=memcached.so" to php.ini

Tags: memcached, php

It says "Floating point exception" while running php-fpm after adding "extension=memcached.so" to php.ini, why?

Comment: What is "it"? Where are you getting this message? What did you try to execute that cause this error to appear?

Comment: @DaveRandom : when i run php-fpm, the screen shows 'Floating point exception'.

Comment: Can you show the full core dump?

Comment: @DaveRandom: plz forgive my ignorance, but what is "full core dump", and how can i get it?

Comment: Does it not show you any more text, is that the only error message you get? I would expect it to dump a load of information about the call stack. It's probably a division by 0 in the memcached code. Are you running the latest `memcached.so`? Where did you get it from and how old is it?

Comment: @DaveRandom: VM_248_255:/usr/lib64 # /usr/local/services/php/sbin/php-fpm 
Floating point exception
VM_248_255:/usr/lib64 #

Comment: I suspect the problem is going to be with `memcached.so`, did you build it from source yourself?

Comment: Yes, i build it myself. And it should have something to with memcached.so. Bcz when i removed extension="memcached.so", php-fpm runs well

Comment: @DaveRandom : The version of memcached is "memcached 1.2.0"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13165/discussion-between-royhu-and-daverandom)

Comment: It's not really worth me joining you in chat over this issue, I don't know enough about memcached to be helpful. What I will say is that you would be better directing this question towards http://www.serverfault.com/ because it is not a programming question it is a compilation problem or a bug in the memcached.so source, and it is more likely there will be someone there who can help